# How does Mongo's eventual consistency work with a large number of data writes?

Tags: mongodb

I have a flow like this:
[image]
I have a Worker that's processing a "large" batch (say, 1M records) and storing the results in Mongo.

Once the batch is complete, a notification message is sent to Publish, which then pulls all the records from Mongo for final publication.

Let's say the Worker write process is done, i.e. it has sent all 1M records to Mongo through a driver.  Mongo is "eventually consistent" so I'm not 100% guaranteed all records are written to physical storage at the time the Notify Publish happens.

When Publish does a 'find' and gets a cursor on the collection holding the batch records, is the cursor smart enough to handle the eventual consistency?

So in practical terms let's imagine 750,000 records are actually physically written by Mongo when Notify Publish happens and Publish does its find.  Will the cursor traverse 750,000 records and stop or will it block or otherwise handle the remaining 250,000 as they're eventually written to disk (which presumably is very likely to happen while publishing of the first 750K)?

Comment: You do realize that "eventual consistency" refers to the replication process between primary and secondary nodes, and also a reason why primary reads should be preferred unless your application can "live with" reading data that may not be the most up to date. You seem to be talking about external worker processes though, and as such is not really related.

Comment: are you using shardind, replication or both in your mongo configuration

Comment: I'm not really clear on the relationships.  We do have replication but not sharding.  In my use case I do need the entire batch to be read by the Publisher.  He can block if needed, but needs it all.  I can do primary reads.  So I think I understand this to mean that if I read primary then I don't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @BlakesSeven already noted in the comments, "eventual consistency" refers to the fact that in a replicated environment, when a write is finished on the primary, it will only be written to the secondaries *eventually*. You can modify this behavior at the cost of reduced write performance by setting the [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/#write-concern-for-replica-sets) to > 1. Setting it to "majority" basically guarantees that a write operation is durable even in case of a failover – though at a (in some cases) drastically reduced performance.

In general here is what happens when you do a write (simplified) with journaling enabled:

1. The operation is checked for being syntactically correct.
2. The query optimizer kicks in and does his stuff. (Irrelevant for this question, so I spare the details).
3. The write operation is applied to the in memory representation of the data set called "private view".
4. Every [commitIntervalMs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.mmapv1.journal.commitIntervalMs), the private view is synced to the journal, with a median of 15 or 50ms, depending on the write concern.
5. On sync, the operation is applied to the shared view. Iirc, this is the point where a **new** connection would be provided with the new data.

So in order to ensure that the data will be readable by the new connection, simply delay the publish notification by `commitIntervalMs` + 1, which, given your batch size, is hardly noticeable.